# Which national parks in Nepal do not legally require you to have a guide?

Tags: national-parks, nepal

I am having difficulty finding out which national parks in Nepal do not legally require you to have a guide, using my phone and local data. There doesn't seem to be a single website, even a Nepali governmental one, to summarise that information. It's easy enough to find out how much entry fees are, but for guide requirements, it seems to be different in every website.

Comment: My experience is that the requirement of a guide is only strictly enforced in Manaslu. In other regions it is possible to negociate your way around. And for many regions you need to obtain the permit through a trekking agency that will be happy to tell you that you absolutely need a guide.

Comment: I trekked the Annapurna Conservation Area earlier this year without a guide... really easy to do too! But as said above, permits/TIMS card are required in nearly all the main national parks.

Comment: A tour guide is legally required. This is also for your safety and security. Plus your dollars goes a long long way in supporting the Nepalese who are continually battling with hunger and poverty.

Answer (score 6):

National parks in Nepal **do not legally require you to have a guide**. [Guidelines, Rules, Acts, Policy, Regulation Collection 2073](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AvMj98dT2hX1JSa28yREJaYWs/view)<sup>Language:
 Nepali</sup> Government of Nepal [Department of National Parks and Wildlife Conservation](http://www.dnpwc.gov.np/), doesn't state anything that make guide compulsory for a tourist.

Two things that I have found concerning this question is: (National parks and Wildlife Reserves only)

1.[image: Law 1st part]

**My translation**: Without entry card provided by authenticated person of the Government of Nepal no person can enter the National park or Hunting Reserves. (other part is exception for Government person)

2.[image: law 2nd part]

**My translation**: Entering in National park or Wildlife Reserves will be your sole responsibility.  If some accidents happen inside National Park or Wildlife Reserves Government of Nepal is not responsible for compensation.

**SO**, legally you are not required to have guide for National Parks or even wildlife reserve in Nepal but if you want one that guide must have license provided by Government.

Comment: The first sentence is confusing. Are you saying that every park is accessible without a guide?

Comment: -1 Manaslu is a clear example where it is required. I've heard of plenty of people that they where stopped at the Jagat checkpoint for not having a guide. I've never heard of anyone being able to enter there without a guide. Because that particular law doesn't say anything about it does not imply that there is no other regulation making it mandatory for some national parks.

Comment: @ptityeti At first Manaslu is not a national park it's a conservation area, so rule and regulation will automatically vary between two, first time looking at this I thought you were talking about Makalu, And secondly the above law is for National park and Wildlife Reserve not for Hunting Reserve and Conservation Area. At last, thank you for prompting me to research more, if there are any more mistakes do let me know.

Comment: You might want to edit these details in you answer to make it more clear. The question is "Which national parks in Nepal do not legally require you to have a guide?". Your answer as it stands reads: "No.". I think you meant to say that "National parks *do not require* you to have a guide." See my edit and feel free to rollback if you think I vandalised your post. :)

Comment: Good point that Manaslu is not a national park. I've retracted my downvote and upvoted. In the list with national parks Shey-Phoksundo looks the most tricky (DNPWC states "Individual trekking is permitted to trek to Ringmo or Phoksundo Lake. The Tran-Himalayan region of inner Dolpa is restricted to group trekking only". But as I went from Ringmo to Mugu without a guide a few months ago, I know that it is possible. My suggestion for improving the answer would be pointing out that many trekking regions are not national parks, but have another protection status.